# How to hide empty Subcategory in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to hide empty Subcategory which are are empty.

I have created subcategory named (2013,2014,2015). They are showing up fine but documents which are stored under different category are still showing Subcategory even though no subcategory was selected when document was uploaded.

How can I hide them without losing other categories?

[image]

thanks.

Comment: I tried the solution - but unfortunately it hides all the other documents which are not under those subcategories. Please advise

Answer (score 5):

You could filter the list view. Go to the ribbon at the top under `Library` then modify this view. About halfway down should be a filter option and select...

1. `Subcategory` for the column choice,
2. `not equal to` for the filter style
3. Leave the third option blank.
4. Go to the bottom of the page, save the view.

Below is an example using `Title` instead of `Subcategory`:

[image]